# how to access the path of folder with japanese and english name with some space in localhost?

Tags: php, directory

It displays warning:no such file when I want to access the file within folder in Japanese and English and some space in between.

I have tried to remove the file within folder in English name without spacing in between using php unlink() function and it works fine but I try to use same function to access folder in Japanese and English and get the problem I mentioned before.

So,How can I access the path and remove the file inside the folder in Japanese and English name?

I appreciate to anyone who can help me to solve this problem.